# junit -проверка вызова метода

Tags: java, junit

У меня есть класс, в котором есть метод `init()` и конструктор. 
Нужно проверить, что в момент создания этого класса (т.е. когда вызывается конструктор) метод `init()` не вызывается.

```
public class SessionsServlet extends HttpServlet {

    ...

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        //
    }

    public  SessionsServlet() {
        //
    }
}
```

Тест:

```
@Test
void isInitInvoke() {
   SessionsServlet  sessionsServlet = new SessionsServlet();

   ??
}
```

По идее можно как-то через библиотеку `Mockito` --
там есть статический метод `verify(sessionsServlet, never()).init();`, но он работает только с моками.

**upd.**

Слегка надуманный пример, но тем не менее.
Предположим есть такой конструктор, и нужно проверить вызвался метод или нет, получается то, что выполняется в конструкторе, никак не отследить?

```
public SessionsServlet() {
    if(someCondition) {
        this.something();
    }
}

public void something(){
    ///
}
```

Comment: Можете анонимный класс сделать, переопределить `init()` и выкинуть исключение. По [jls-15.9.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5.1) для не внутренних классов явно будет вызван конструктор суперкласса, с совпадающей сигнатурой, плюс как обычно при инициализации сначала произойдет инициализация суперклассов, включая вызов `init`, если он где-то есть. Но мне тоже как-то такой подход не нравится, возможно стоит задать более общий вопрос по поводу подходов к тестированию, с более полным описанием проблемы.

Comment: Надо протеcтировать просто код, который условие меняет в `if`

Answer (score 1):

1. Конструктуры не подлежат тестированию. Если вам нужно тестировать констуртор, то этот код, вероятно, с душком.
2. Конструктор - это необычный публичный метод. Если вы хотите протестировать, не выполняется ли `init()` метод, значит он может выполнятся? Следовательно вам нужен контекст, при котором этот клас создается. Т.б. вам нужно тестировать код, который этот конструктор вызывает. Там вы мокаете ваш класс и уже известным вам методом `verify(sessionsServlet, never()).init();` проверяете, что поведение такое, как вы ожидаете.

Comment: обновил пост ....